# Custom font not working with EMUI or custom Android OS

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, fonts, huawei-mobile-services

I am developing an android app and using the custom font Pacifico. In the emulator everything works fine, but in my actual device is not, My phone is **Huawei Y6**. I wonder if this is an issue with **EMUI** (The OS of Huawei) rather than how develop the app.

Comment: Hello, send the issue to developer@huawei.com They will answer your question.

Comment: So this is an issue with the device then. Thank you, I will send an email.

Comment: Anybody find solution for it?